# Can't make yellow disappear with HSV (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I have the follow image:

[image: src]

What I want to do is to keep all red figures.

Using this code..

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def callback(x):
    pass

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('image')

ilowH = 0
ihighH = 179
ilowS = 0
ihighS = 255
ilowV = 0
ihighV = 255

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('lowH', 'image', ilowH, 179, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('highH', 'image', ihighH, 179, callback)

cv2.createTrackbar('lowS', 'image', ilowS, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('highS', 'image', ihighS, 255, callback)

cv2.createTrackbar('lowV', 'image', ilowV, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('highV', 'image', ihighV, 255, callback)

while True:
    # grab the frame
    frame = cv2.imread('color_test.png')

    # get trackbar positions
    ilowH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lowH', 'image')
    ihighH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('highH', 'image')
    ilowS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lowS', 'image')
    ihighS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('highS', 'image')
    ilowV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lowV', 'image')
    ihighV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('highV', 'image')

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_hsv = np.array([ilowH, ilowS, ilowV])
    higher_hsv = np.array([ihighH, ihighS, ihighV])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, higher_hsv)

    frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    # show thresholded image
    cv2.imshow('image', frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF  # large wait time to remove freezing
    if k == 113 or k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

... max I can obtain is this:

[image: output]

How can I get rid of yellow colour and keep the 3 red figures ? Is HSL a good alternative to use in cases like this ?
Keep in mind that the center red it's not the same as the other 2; one is full red (255, 0, 0) the other are less (237, 28, 36) RGB.

Comment: the red hue range is split around 0 (0°) and 180 (360°) so you can't work with a lower-and-higher-threshold-area. Hue is a circular value range.

Comment: I tried to go up and down with the sliders but max I can obtain (by keeping all the 3 red figures) it's with the yellow included. If I delete also the yellow, the red square (upper left) and bottom ellipse disappear also.

Comment: Invert/negate the image (pixel=255-pixel) and choose cyan pixels using `inRange()`

Comment: Just like Micka hinted, the red hue is split. Simplest thing you can do is save the hue channel in grayscale and then inspect the values, e.g. using some paint program. You will notice that the top and bottom red objects have hue value of 179, and the middle square has hue value of 0. You can't select all 3 using a single `inRange` call -- you need two, and then combine the masks.

Comment: another way is to choose a target hue value and a range, then shift the hue channel so that your target value is at shifted value 90 and then process a single inRange call to 90-range/2 to 90+range/2. Probably not efficient but sweet :)

Comment: About HSV and masks I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331944/finding-red-color-using-python-opencv) which promise good..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did something similar a while back and ended up defining my own basic colors in HSV space, including monochrome definitions (which I admit are a little arbitrary).

Anyway, as those in the comments stated, in HSV, the red hue is split, so I made a simple function to combine any colors I defined to easily create masks for them:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

HSV_RANGES = {
    # red is a major color
    'red': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([0, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([20, 255, 255])
        },
        {
            'lower': np.array([161, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([180, 255, 255])
        }
    ],
    # yellow is a minor color
    'yellow': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([21, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([40, 255, 255])
        }
    ],
    # green is a major color
    'green': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([41, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([80, 255, 255])
        }
    ],
    # cyan is a minor color
    'cyan': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([81, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([100, 255, 255])
        }
    ],
    # blue is a major color
    'blue': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([101, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([140, 255, 255])
        }
    ],
    # violet is a minor color
    'violet': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([141, 39, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([160, 255, 255])
        }
    ],
    # next are the monochrome ranges
    # black is all H & S values, but only the lower 25% of V
    'black': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([0, 0, 0]),
            'upper': np.array([180, 255, 63])
        }
    ],
    # gray is all H values, lower 15% of S, & between 26-89% of V
    'gray': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([0, 0, 64]),
            'upper': np.array([180, 38, 228])
        }
    ],
    # white is all H values, lower 15% of S, & upper 10% of V
    'white': [
        {
            'lower': np.array([0, 0, 229]),
            'upper': np.array([180, 38, 255])
        }
    ]
}


def create_mask(hsv_img, colors):
    """
    Creates a binary mask from HSV image using given colors.
    """

    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    mask = np.zeros((hsv_img.shape[0], hsv_img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)

    for color in colors:
        for color_range in HSV_RANGES[color]:
            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
            mask += cv2.inRange(
                hsv_img,
                color_range['lower'],
                color_range['upper']
            )

    return mask
```

Applying it to your example (which I named "color_shapes.png"), I get good results:

```
img = cv2.imread('color_shapes.png')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

red_mask = create_mask(img_hsv, ['red'])

mask_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img_hsv, img_hsv, mask=red_mask)
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible. Seems a good example. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Works pretty good. About the values, did you find somewhere or you just calculated them ? What if I have do create about 20 HSV ranges ? I have to do this manually or can I find them ?

Comment: Yes, I calculated them, starting with figuring out the center point for the 3 "major" colors. I named these major because they span a larger range of the hue values before what my eye could discern as a different color. It ended up dividing up pretty nicely with a hue range of 40 for the major colors and 20 for the 3 minor colors, covering the hue space of 180. The monochrome values are a bit more subjective.

Answer (score 2):

#### Background

I would like to propose an alternate approach. For segmenting/isolating dominant colors (red, blue, green and yellow); the [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space) gives you more freedom. In HSV space, you have to alter the values present across all three channels. But in LAB space, you can just focus on 1 channel, depending on the color you want to segment.

LAB space has 3 channels (2 color channels and 1 brightness channel):

- L-channel: incorporates the brightness
- A-channel: incorporates the red and green color
- B-channel: incorporates the blue and yellow color

If you look closely at the **a-axis** in the following diagram, colors red and green can be segmented at the extremes of that axis.

[image]

#### Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('colored_blobs.png')
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a_channel = lab[:,:,1]
```

[image]

As you can see, the red colored objects are in the brighter end of the spectrum. For this image, I subtract pixel intensity 10 from the maximum in `a_channel` and set it as the threshold:

```
th = cv2.threshold(dst,int(np.max(a_channel) - 10),255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

[image]

All that's left to be done is masking:

```
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = th)
```

[image]

#### Added Info:

I have written a similar answer to detect **green** color here: [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image with Python OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/72264323#72264323)

> Performing the same operation on the B-channel will help segment blue/yellow colors.