# How to filter colors from 16-bit values from .las file?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `.las` file with content, like this:

```
   array([( 860297,  472942, 67187, 11051, 73, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12079, 11051,  9252),
           ( 859318,  473132, 67336,  8995, 73, 0, 0, 0, 1,  9252,  8995,  9509),
           ( 859941,  473665, 67550, 12079, 73, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12079, 12850, 10023),
           ...,
           (1057593, 1184341, 75212, 19018, 73, 0, 0, 0, 1, 20303, 19275, 16191),
           (1057764, 1184161, 74734, 14906, 73, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15934, 14906, 13878),
           (1057548, 1184058, 74881, 26214, 73, 0, 0, 0, 1, 28784, 25957, 21074)],
          dtype=[('X', '<i4'), ('Y', '<i4'), ('Z', '<i4'), ('intensity', '<u2'), ('bit_fields', 'u1'),
                 ('raw_classification', 'u1'), ('scan_angle_rank', 'i1'), ('user_data', 'u1'),
                 ('point_source_id', '<u2'), ('red', '<u2'), ('green', '<u2'), ('blue', '<u2')])
```

As I have found in .las files values in RGB are stored in 16-bit colors. I wrote 2 functions - convert colors to 8-bit:

```
opened_file = open("my.las") #example
colors = opened_file.points[["red", "green", 'blue']]
>>> array([(12079, 11051,  9252), (9252,  8995,  9509), (12079, 12850, 10023), ...])

def eightbitify(colour):
    return colour/256
```

Next I am trying to convert colors to `HSV`, so I will have a possibility to filter specific colors:

```
def to_hsv(rgb: np.ndarray):
    empty_image = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    empty_image[0, 0] = list(reversed(rgb))
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(empty_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    return list(reversed(hsv[0, 0]))
```

I did not manage to find better solution for this, because OpenCV needs image - so I am creating image for 1 pixel and converting it (so ugly :/ ). The problem is that values which I recieve does not match any internet RGB-HSV calculators results.
I am using those functions in this way:

```
def convert_color(rgb_16: np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
    converted_color = np.array([int(eightbitify(rgb_16[0])), int(eightbitify(rgb_16[1])), int(eightbitify(rgb_16[2]))])
    converted_hsv = to_hsv(converted_color)
    return converted_hsv

for color in colors:
    converted = convert_color(color)
```

**So my questions are:**
**1.** What is the best way to convert RGB values to HSV from my `opened_file.points` initial array?
**2.** How can I filter specific colors from my `opened_file.points` only using numpy? May be I can apply some converting function to RGB values, etc?
Unfortunately, I have a very small experience with numpy, so I need help. Thank you!

Comment: Two things... You reverse your RGB values to make them BGR to match the OpenCV ordering, but then use `cvtColor()` with `RGB2HSV`! You should either not reverse your list (leaving it as RGB) and using `cvtColor()` as you are, OR, you should reverse your list and use `cvtColor()` with `BGR2HSV`. Secondly, note that OpenCV scales the Hue component by a factor of 2, so that 360 degrees of the Hue circle fit in a `uint8` which can handle up to 255, so a 360 degree Hue becomes 180 which fits - that's why it won't match online converters.

Comment: A couple of other things... What is a `.las` file, and which Python modules are you using to read yours? Can you share a sample file - Dropbox, Google Drive? What is the motivation for your question - to learn Numpy? to speed up processing - what's too slow? Do you want to segment some image or filter it? I don't understand what the actual issue is. Is the file big? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `.las` file it is a lidar file, the example you can find here - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c1ec264064fd4618c90213c67194403020200421214526/8ff60235513304fe0db8378829ba25eb20200421214551/ed3358. I am using `pylas` to open it. Visually open it you can use CloudCompare tool. I need to "flatten" this image - leave only ground and remove trees, houses, etc. So I want to remove all green points (trees) at first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with your image type but can hopefully help you with the Numpy and OpenCV aspects.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pylas
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open file
las = pylas.read('W2.las')

# Extract all the red values into a Numpy array, likewise green and blue
R = las.points["red"]
G = las.points["green"]
B = las.points["blue"]

# Make a Numpy image by stacking the RGB values and converting to uint8
BGR = (np.dstack((B,G,R))>>8).astype(np.uint8)

# Convert to HSV
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(BGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define lower and uppper limits of what we call "green"
range_lo = np.array([70,30,30])
range_hi = np.array([90,255,255])

# Mask image to only select greens
mask = cv.inRange(HSV,range_lo,range_hi)

# Change image to red where we found green
image[mask>0]=(0,0,255)

cv.imwrite("result.png",image)
```

At the moment, I don't know the shape of the image, so it comes out as a long line of 44 million pixels, but it just needs a `reshape()` to make it correct. Note that each True/False value in `mask` will be the index into your list of pixels and indicate whether that pixel is green or not.

You may have to work with the lower and upper values of the `range` parameter - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215020/2836621).

Stack Overflow user @nathancy made a rather neat HSV colour selector with sliders [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58194879/2836621).

Comment: thank you! it works after some edits to .las realities :) one more question - `range_lo` and `range_hi` are boundaries for the green color in HSV? in results I see it has left too much gray color. can you give a tip what better values to leave only green?

Comment: The second parameter in HSV is Saturation. If saturation is zero, you have grey tones, if Saturation is 255 you have vivid colours. So maybe increase the low limit of saturation so your greens must be greener:-) That would mean `range_lo=np.array(70, 80, 30)` or somesuch.